# Se está notificando al usuario que el rol fue insertado o actualizado, incluso si ya existe en la DB

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, mvc

Estoy haciendo un formulario de creación y gestión de roles de usuario el típico crud.
La funcionalidad como tal está bien, me explico:
Si el usuario agrega un rol que no existe, el nombre de rol se agrega sin problema a la DB y manda el mensaje que el rol se ha agregado correctamente. Pero si el usuario agrega un nombre de rol que ya existe, este no se agrega a la DB pero le muestra al usuario el mensaje de que el nombre de rol se ha agregado y no le muestra el mensaje de que ese nombre ya existe en la DB.
Lo mismo pasa a la hora de actualizar un registro: si el usuario le cambia el nombre al rol por uno ya existente en la DB, este no actualiza a ese nombre, pero igual le informa que el rol se ha actualizado.
Así que con lo que estoy batallando es que muestre los mensajes que corresponden a cada acción.

Estoy trabajando con Modelo Vista Controlador con php8.1.
Estas son las funciones con las cuales agrego y actualizo los roles.
Estas se encuentran en el Modelo.

```
//guardar roles
        public function insertRol(string $rol){
            $return ='';
            $this->strRol =$rol;
            $sql ="SELECT * FROM roles WHERE rol_nombre='{$this->strRol}';";
            $request = $this->select_all($sql);
            
            if(empty($request)){
                $query_insert = "INSERT INTO roles(rol_nombre) VALUES(?);";
                $arrData = array($this->strRol);
                $request_insert= $this->insert($query_insert, $arrData);
                $return = $request_insert;
            }
            else{
                $return = 'exist';
            }
            return $return;
        }

        //actualizar registro 
        public function updateRol(int $idrol, string $rol, int $status){
            $this->intIdRol = $idrol;
            $this->strRol = $rol;
            $this->intStatus = $status;
            $sql="SELECT * FROM roles WHERE rol_nombre= '$this->strRol' AND rol_id != $this->intIdRol";
            $request=$this->select_all($sql);

            if(empty($request)){
                $sql="UPDATE roles SET rol_nombre =?, rol_estado= ? WHERE rol_id= $this->intIdRol";
                $arrData= array($this->strRol, $this->intStatus);
                $request= $this->update($sql, $arrData);
            }
            else{
                $request='exist';
            }
            return $request;
        }
```

Supongo que están funcionando bien ya que ejecutan como se debe las acciones de insertar y actualizar.

Y es aquí donde yo siento que está el problema en el controlador, específicamente en la función de *setRol* que es esta:

```
public function setRol(){
            $intIdRol = intval($_POST['idRol']);
            $strRol =  strClean($_POST['rol']);
            $intStatus = intval($_POST['listStatus']);
            
            if($intIdRol ==0){
                $request_rol = $this->model->insertRol($strRol);
                $option = 1;    
            }
            else{
                $request_rol = $this->model->updateRol($intIdRol, $strRol, $intStatus);
                $option = 2;
            }
            
             //mandamos respuesta 
             if($request_rol >0){
                if($option == 1){
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'El rol se ha agregado correctamente');
                }
                else{
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'El rol se ha sido actualizado');
                }
            }
            else if($request_rol == 'exist'){
                $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'El nombre de rol ya existe');
            }
            else{
                $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'No fue posible agregar el rol a la DB');
            }
            echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            die();
        }
```

No sé por qué no se ejecuta el `else if($request_rol == 'exist'){}` que es el que mandaría el mensaje de error, y cuando le quito el `else` y lo dejo solo en `if` muestra el mensaje pero ya no deja actualizar los roles.

Comment: Revisa el valor de la variable $request_rol en el primer if  , parece que el if($request_rol >0) esta dejando pasar mas datos de los esperados.

Comment: Gracias por tomarte tiempo de responder. La solución era quitar un string que recibía como respuesta por un 1 o un 0.

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a ese detalle se encuentra en el método del modelo actualizar registro, en específico en la parte donde se manda como respuesta un string que en este caso es un 'exist'. Solo lo cambie por un valor de 1 o 0, o sea un true o un false y se me solucionó el problema.

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta.